# Combobox item source does not work in silverlight datagrid

Tags: silverlight

I want to bind ItemSource for a combobox within silverlight datagrid.
It doesn't show the bound values. I have a dynamic ItemSource value which is coming from
database. How can I do that?

Comment: <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header="And/Or" Width="Auto">
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AndOrs}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

Comment: public ObservableCollection<string> AndOrs
        {
            get
            {
                return _andor;
            }
            set
            {
                _andor = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("AndOrs");
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Currently ur combobox can`t find the value coz it trying to find it in item`s(which DataGrid binded to) fields named "AndOrs". If u wand to bind column to independent of DataGrid on the whole, u should use full path/rel. souce for search needed property in DataContext and binding to it. For example if collection used for DataGrid`s ItemsSource defined near AndOrs:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=sdk:DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.AndOrs}"/>
```

P.S.
As i guess AndOrs property is not defined in item u use for DataGrid to bind to.

Comment: AncestorType is new in SL5 but because of component i'm using i have to use SL4 which AncestorType is not suppored. is there any command instead of AncestorType?

Comment: there are no "AncestorType" equivalent in SL4

Comment: do you have any alternative way for this in SL4?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The best I could find for SL4 is to use a static resource.

See here: http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2011/05/06/Binding-a-Datagride28099s-ComboBox.aspx

Or, by creating the static resource in xaml: http://forums.silverlight.net/post/370135.aspx